# Обновление формы по F5

Tags: javascript, form, select

Есть `form`, на которой имеется img и select, которые меняются функцией. Все работает нормально до тех пор, пока пользователь не вызывает обновление окна обозревателя по F5. После этого рисунку возвращается src, который был прописан в коде, а не тот, который назначен функцией обработки select. Как сделать, что бы при открытии и при обновлении страницы, значение src для img, бралось из значения select? Желательно не использовать cookies и сессии.
Примерный текст программы:

```
<form id="calcpr" method="POST" onsubmit="Count(this); return true;" name="calcpr">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

   //Массивы картинок
   var putimg="templates/img/" //путь к каталогу картинок
   var Fcolimg=new Array(putimg+"F1green.jpg", putimg+"F1Blue.jpg", putimg+"F1brown.jpg", putimg+"F1black.jpg" );

   function FrontColfimg(id) {document.images['Fronttickket'].src=Fcolimg[document.getElementById(id).value-1];}
   </script>
<select name="CFticket" id="CFticket" onchange="FrontColfimg(id)">
        <option value="1">Зеленый</option>
    <option value="2">Синий</option>
    <option selected="" value="3" >Коричневый</option>
    <option value="4">Черный</option>
</select>
<img id="Fronttickket" name="Fronttickket" alt="Образец лицевой стороны билета" width="136" height="96" align="center" src="templates/img/F1Brown.jpg"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После

```
<img id="Fronttickket" name="Fronttickket" alt="Образец лицевой стороны билета" width="136" height="96" align="center" src="templates/img/F1Brown.jpg"/>
```

пишем

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    FrontColfimg('CFticket')
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо Fuzzz3r , действительно ответ лежал на поверхности.